# How can I make a verified symbol in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rich

I am working on a project that uses Python to download and install applications. The repos where the application info is stored has a line in `json` that states if the user is verified, this is then converted to a `True` or `False` variable. After downloading the info on the user it prints the info on screen using the `rich.print` function, in the `rich` module. I want to be able to print a verified symbol, like on Twitter, how can I do this?

```
manifest.json

{
  "Name": "Test package",
  "License": "Public Domain",
  "Developer": "Hearth OS",
  "DeveloperWWW": "https://hearth-os.github.io/",
  "Description": "Hello World package.",
  "Verified": "True",
  "Version": "0.1",
  "AppID": "com.hearth-os.test"
}
```

```
main.py (Lines 72-90)

# Write and open manifest.json
open("manifest.json", 'wb').write(r.content)
jsonFile = open("manifest.json", "r")
manifest = json.load(jsonFile)

# Read `manifest`
name = manifest['Name']
license = manifest['License']
developer = manifest['Developer']
www = manifest['DeveloperWWW']
description = manifest['Description']
verified = manifest['Verified']
version = manifest['Version']
id = manifest['AppID']

# Print `manifest`
rich.print('Package: ' + name)
rich.print('Developer: [link=' + www + ']' + developer + '[/link]')
rich.print('License: ' + license)
```

Comment: You can output any Unicode character you like, perhaps something like U+2611, U+2705, or U+2714.

Comment: Twitter itself is displaying a small icon, not text, so that's beyond the scope of the `rich` library.

Comment: Is there a library I could use to display icons?

Comment: That depends entirely on your terminal, and whether it can display graphics.

Comment: So I'm guessing you can't if it uses `TTY`, right?

Comment: Again, that depends. For example, iTerm has escape sequences that allow you to display the contents of an image file directly in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "verified symbol" is a unicode character you can just print it:

```
if verified:
    print("✅")
```

If in python2 you might need to specify an encoding at the top of your file or you will get an error. UTF-8 is a common choice (and the default in python3)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

You can also avoid embedding unicode literal characters in your code by using the unicode escape sequence (you need to look up the code for your symbol of choice):

```
print("\u2705")
```